# QFile dont work when executed by .app - Macosx

Tags: c++, macos, qt

Hi guys I'm using QFile to create and populate one file to be read for a function.

That is a example of my file.cpp:

```
// host should be /Users/myUser/Desktop/myapp-gui/debug/bin/myapp-gui.app/Contents/MacOS
const QString sibling_file_path = host + "/../../../";
QFile::remove(sibling_file_path + "provider.http");
QFile fileProvider(sibling_file_path + "provider.http");
// file created - /Users/myUsser/Desktop/myapp-gui/debug/bin/provider.http

//write provider.http
if(fileProvider.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text)){
    QTextStream txtStream(&fileProvider);

    txtStream << "HTTP/1.0 200 PROVIDER\n";
    txtStream << "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\n";
    txtStream << "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET\n";
    txtStream << "Cache-Control: no-cache\n";
    txtStream << "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";

    txtStream << "{\"provider\":\""+serviceName+"\",\"service\":\""+plan+"\"}";


    txtStream.seek(0);
    fileProvider.close();
}
```

Until now everything OK, If run the QT build I can see my file inside the folder.

But, if I create the apple application from my code - "aplication.app" and try to run by app (double click) my function doesn't create the file.

If I open my app content: ~/aplication.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp-gui and call the function to create my provider works!

Its looking like permission problem :(

The same code work in Linux and Windows

FIXED << The problem was the wrong path to call the file

Comment: You should check for IO errors, and debug print the error messages.

Comment: Looks like it's probably a permission issue. Why aren't you writing the file to a user or temp folder?

Comment: The problem is  how I was getting the path, I need to use QStandardPaths to get the app path.

Comment: You are aware, that changing files inside your Application bundle will break code signing? Also, you should not rely on users that have write permissions to the application bundles they are executing. A better solution would be to use temporary files.